# Issue importing wordpress db into godaddy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a local working Wordpress site and now I'm trying to import the db on a site hosted in Godaddy but it's telling me it **can't connect to the database**.
Basically I need **db name**, **user** and **pass** in the wp-config and I created manually the db in Godaddy to make sure the **table prefixes** are the same. Also, Godaddy won't take `localhost` in the wp-config, you have to use their ip address with a port, something like: **127.0.0.1:1234**. The only thing I haven't checked yet are my privileges. Not sure what the defaults are in Godaddy.

For those Godaddy users, Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Have you asked the people over at GoDaddy? I'm sure they have more users that uses WP and know what to do.

Comment: You moderators have serious problems. I wonder if there are moderators for moderators?

Comment: I don't know what "moderators" you're referring to. It's basically just users (with more or less rep) here. Your questions though, is very specific to one specific hosting company and their defaults/settings, which is why I recommend that you contact them to get all the info you need. It's not a general programming question, which SO is meant for. There are also guidelines which explains how a good question should be structured/what topics is on/off topic etc. Read here: [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 1):

don't upload your local wordpress database like that!

When you create articles, post, pages, etc locally with wordpress it fills your database with your local links. Even if you push it to your new godady database, all the links won't work.

Here is what you have to do:

1. Create a new database in godady  (done)
2. Create a new user and password for the db with all the priviledge (you have to this, very important)
3. Upload and install wordpress to your new domain (follow the install tutorial)
4. Register your dbname, user and password (localhost will work as the db is one godady, but you can put the IP)
5. Upload your local theme to the new domain (update only the theme, uploads and plugins).
6. If needed, set up the htacess and permissions to be able to upload files
7. Download WP Migrate DB on your local project and export the db with your production website info. If you are unsure, install the plugin on the production site too, simulate an export and copy the info to your local project
8. Upload the migrate database to gadady and then rock'n roll =)

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.